# How to avoid mysql table crash

Tags: php, mysql

I have found that one of my mysql tables (with MYISAM engine)  crashed, yesterday the same thing with another table.

I think the cause is the overload of my VPS in these last days (because both these tables are used to store many impressions)

I tried to repair the table but it was not possible, so the only solution was to truncate the table.

The table is used to store many banner-impressions every day (about 200'000 x day), the query is a simple PHP INSERT, like this:

```
"INSERT INTO TABLE ( user, banner, datetime, ip, page, lang ) VALUES ( '$userid', '$bannerid', '$now', '$ip', '$refurl', '$lang' )"
```

The database use the MyISAM engine and utf8_general_ci. I think the problem is the server overload and I'm wondering if is better to change engine to InnoDB. when the table is crashed was about 50MB, I optimize the table every 30 min with a cronjob.

My question is, how can I avoid that the mysql tables crash again in the future? I just need to change the engine from MYISAM to InnoDB?

Comment: You gave us minimal information regarding your problem. Can you provide us the scenarios or instances when the table crashed? What are the transactions/queries made? The schema of your table can be helpful but not really necessary.

Comment: The table is used to store many banner-impressions every day (about 200'000 x day), the query is a simple PHP INSERT, like this: "INSERT INTO TABLE ( user, banner, datetime, ip, page, lang ) VALUES ( '$userid', '$bannerid', '$now', '$ip', '$refurl', '$lang' )". The database use the MyISAM engine and utf8_general_ci. I think the problem is the server overload and i'm wondering if is better to change engine to InnoDB. when the table is crashed was about 50MB, i optimize the table every 30 min with cronjob